# Error in conditional operator

Tags: c#

I have this code which is working fine

```
if (dt.Rows.Count < 0)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate")
        {
            row[column] = DateTime.MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            row[column] = 0;
        }
    }

    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string));
    col.DefaultValue = "0";
    dt.Columns.Add(col);
}

return dt;
```

This `DataTable` has these columns with mentioned datatype:

- Id: Int
- full_name: string
- user_name: string
- password: string
- user_email: string
- role: string
- CreatedDate: Datetime

This code I am using in a web api controller. It returns data from a SQL query in json format

But if the `DataTable` is empty, then to prevent returning an empty array in json, I'm using this code; in case of empty `DataTable`, it will return zero in every field.

Now I am converting this code in one line (ternary operator) as follows:

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    row[column] = (column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate") ? DateTime.MinValue : 0;
}

dt.Rows.Add(row);

DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string));
col.DefaultValue = "0";
dt.Columns.Add(col);

return dt;
```

I also tried these two approaches:

```
row[column] = (column.DataType == DateTime) ? DateTime.MinValue : 0;
```

and

```
column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate" ? (row[column] = DateTime.MinValue) : (row[column] = 0);
```

But they do not work

Error is:

> Type of conditional expression can not be determined because there is no implicit conversion between System.DatTime and int

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary operator `?:` must return values of the same type (or where the second can be implicitly converted to the first).

Yours is trying to return either a `DateTime` (first) or `int` (second) and thus a conversion doesn't exist.

You need to do it in one of number of ways.

Code it with an `if` (as you have already done):

```
    if (column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate")
    {
        row[column] = DateTime.MinValue;
    }
    else
    {
        row[column] = 0;
    }
```

Since `row[column]` is of type `object` you can cast the `DateTime` to `object`:

```
    row[column] = (column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate") ? (object)DateTime.MinValue : 0;
```

Or, if you want to map multiple columns, do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> defaults = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "CreatedDate", DateTime.MinValue },
    { "full_name", "n/a" },
    { "Id", default(int) },
};

foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    row[column] = defaults.ContainsKey(column.ColumnName) ? defaults[column.ColumnName] : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your ternary operator returns two different types of data depending on the case: If true it returns a `DateTime`, if false it returns an `int` of `0`. The you assign the result into the column which is of `DateTime` type - and as the error states there is no implicit convert from the `int` to the `DateTime`:

```
row[column] = (column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate") ? (object)DateTime.MinValue : 0;
```

Comment: I think you miss the point. It's not a runtime exception, but compiler error.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I know it is a compiler error :) The column of `CreatedDate: Datetime` is of `DateTime` and the assignment is of an `int`.

Comment: Hmm, that why you wrote *"as the **exception** states"*. And where is the solution? IMO it needs `object` cast, e.g. `(object)DateTime.MinValue`

Comment: @IvanStoev - true :) wrote wrong word. Corrected. I couldn't suggest what to do instead as it is for OP to determine what value to use in the `else`

Comment: row[column] = (column.ColumnName == "CreatedDate") ? (object)DateTime.MinValue : 0;

Comment: @IvanStoev - okay :) understood my mistake - corrected. Thanks for explaining.